# find number of git pull/fetch from your repo

Tags: github

Is there a way to find how many times people have fetched/pulled from your git repository?  I see a "Pull Requests" tab.  Is that it?

Comment: Unless you are hosting the repository on your own machine and implement a counter, or your hosting service gives you access to this information, you can't obtain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that you fork a project and correct an error in that project. You can send a pull request to the owner of that project so he knows you made changes that he probably is interested on.

You can see how many people watch/forked your repository but as far as I know there's no way you can see how many people fetched from your git repository